# How do get the list from @ResponseBody in JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC, I have controller with a method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/listReader", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Reader> getListReader(ModelMap model) {

        return libraryService.getAllReaders();
    }
```

But I do not know:

- How can use list (that I get from method `getListReader` by `@ResponseBody`) in JSP?
- How can I get list in JSP?
- How do to display a list in JSP-page?
- How do to get the list from `@ResponseBody` in JSP?

Give an example, please.

Comment: How does your jsp request spring MVC? What is the mediatype returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. `@ResponseBody` is basically telling Spring: take the object I (method) return and use any serializer you have that supports it and write it directly to the body of the HTTP response. **There's no JSP involved here.**

Instead you should add the list to the model and return the `String` view name of your JSP.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listReader", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getListReader(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("someKey", libraryService.getAllReaders());
    return "my-jsp";
}
```

then you can use EL in the JSP to retrieve it

```
<h3>${someKey}</h3>
```

Use JSTL to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listReader", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

That defines an *Endpoint*.
I would suggest using `RequestMethod.GET` than `RequestMethod.POST`, since you want something from the server not `POSTING` something to the server.
On the other Hand, if you want to use that information on a JSP, there are two ways:

1) Some view could consume that information via a `http-GET`-Request like [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) in jQuery or [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest). After you got the data, you can insert it in your HTML

2) Instead of using `ajax` you could display it directly on the page.
Then, you have to put your List into a [Model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html), which you can acces on your JSP with `Expression Language`. Then you have to remove the `@ResponseBody` and return an according view instead.